# With nestjs / node / npm project how to override a transitive dependency

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, nestjs

I have a nestjs / node / npm project and trying to override a transitive dependency due to security vulnerability.

The project that seems to include it is:

```json
"@nestjs/common": "7.6.18",
```

And that project includes axios `0.21.1`, I want to upgrade to axios `0.21.2`

In my `package.json` I tried using the overrides feature with the following.

```json
},
"overrides": {
    "axios": "0.21.2"
},
"jest": {
```

But then I get this entry when I run `npm list`.

> ```
> npm list --depth=4 
>
> │ ├─┬ axios@0.21.1 invalid: "0.21.2" from node_modules/@nestjs/common
> ```

And only seems to include axios `0.21.2`.

How do I upgrade a transitive dependency?

I am mostly using the nest wrappers:

nest build, etc

npm --version - 8.3.1

node --version - v17.4.0

Comment: change that `"0.21.2"` to `"0.25.0"`. Using _overrides_ in that way should work. See https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-json#overrides

Comment: This may have been fixed by doing npm update first and then npm install

Comment: Also is there a way to exclude a transitive dependency.

Answer (score 0):

You can try resolutions in npm -

```json
{
  "resolutions": {
    "axios": "0.21.2"
  }
}
```

And then force to install it using preinstall.

```json
"scripts": {
  "preinstall": "npx npm-force-resolutions"
}
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-force-resolutions

Comment: I think this is fixed by keeping overrides and doing npm update and then npm install